# Visual Studio setup project freezes

Tags: c#, setup-project

All, 
    I am having an issue when installing a project in a production environment, the installer (VS setup project) runs its course, installs shortcuts/files, sits on completing setup, and never gets to the "finished" step. Logs show that custom actions run fine, cleanup action runs fine, but never goes any further than the cleanup action.

Any ideas on why we may be running into this issue?

Thanks!

http://pastebin.com/d6MDi1sS

there is a log from the last install

Comment: Is the installation process doing anything at all or does it just sit idle with no CPU or IO activity? I assume that you couldn't find any entries in any of the logs that provide more information, right?

Comment: I have provided a log, but no its sitting at 0 cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this doesn't happen, as I'm sure you know. I'd take your custom actions out and see if it finishes ok. Your CA may seem to finish but maybe isn't finishing properly. Note that it says it lost the connection to the custom action server. This could mean that one of your custom actions failed catastrophically near its exit and crashed the custom action server. So it's most likely going to be something in your code or calling sequence, depending on what kind of CA you have exactly.